# Adding string to verbatim string literal

Tags: c#, json, string-literals, verbatim-string

I am trying to construct a raw `json` string as below to send it out in http request

```
var requestContent = @"{
                    ""name"": ""somename"",
                    ""address"": ""someaddress""
}";
```

Instead of having name and address value hardcoded I was hoping to supply them from below variables

```
string name = "someName";
string address = "someAddress";
```

But the below does not work. Any idea ?

```
var requestContent = @"{
                        ""name"": \" + name \",
                        ""address"": \" + address \"
    }";
```

Comment: Why not use a JSON serializer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
var requestContent = @"{
    ""name"": """ + name + @""",
    ""address"": """ + address + @"""
}";
```

Or, you could use `string.Format`:

```
var requestContent = string.Format(@"{
    ""name"": ""{0}"",
    ""address"": ""{1}""
}", name, address);
```

Or you could use an actual JSON serializer.

Comment: I would never have figured that out. Thank you.

Comment: I spent *** days looking for this answer, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use a verbatim string together with interpolation as well:

```
var requestContent = $@"{{
    ""name"": ""{name}"",
    ""address"": ""{address}""
}}";
```

EDIT: For this to work you have to make sure that curly braces you want in the output are doubled up (just like the quotes). Also, first `$`, then `@`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead use [`Newtonsoft.JSON JObject()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateJsonDynamic.htm) like

```
dynamic myType = new JObject();
myType.name = "Elbow Grease";
myType.address = "someaddress";

Console.WriteLine(myType.ToString());
```

Will generate JSON string as

```
 {
  "name": "Elbow Grease",
  "address": "someaddress"
 }
```